# How to boot the linux of riscv-poky on ZedBoard?

Tags: riscv

I want to boot linux of riscv-poky on ZedBoard.

I've changed MACHINE to riscv64 in conf/local.conf, and created image via `bitbake core-image-riscv`. After that, I've checked that the linux is booted successfully on spike via `runspike riscv64`.

By the way, when I boot linux on ZedBoard with same vmlinux and rootfs, it is not running after printing the RISCV logo. The command is below:

```
./fesvr-zynq +disk=/sdcard/poky/core-image-riscv-riscv64.ext2 bbl /sdcard/poky/vmliux-riscv64.bin
              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrr       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rrrrrrrrrrrrr       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rr                vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
rr            vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rr
rrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrr
rrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrr
rrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vvvvvv      rrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      vv      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr          rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

       INSTRUCTION SETS WANT TO BE FREE
```

Comment: Were you able to boot linux with the prebuilt disk image or a busybox disk image on the zedboard?

Comment: Yes. I can boot linux with both prebuilt and busybox disk image.

Comment: zedboard is an fpga board, which riscv cpu are you flash into it? try to look into address map. You may need to rebuild linux image for your cpu.