# how to rebuild bbl with payload option

Tags: riscv

I'm rebuilding fesvr, pk and bbl run applications on a zedboard. fester, pk runs well, but bbl seems to be built with a dummy payload.

Does anyone know how to rebuilt bbl with proper payload? When I boot riscv-linux with "$ fesvr-zedboard +disk=/sdcard/riscv/root.bin bbl /sdcard/riscv/vmlinux", the "R" logo shows up, and then the console puts "bbl is built with dummy payload. Rebuild it using --with-payload= option".

I looked at the payload.S assembly code under riscv-tools/pk/bbl, it seems the building process wants to include a correct program that sets up something. Does anyone know how to write such a payload code file for zed board, or can I find it somewhere?

One more question, I found riscv-poky to be a better linux distribution. Do I need to use the same command, i.e., fesvr xxx bbl yyy to boot riscv-poky? I've read other ppl have encountered trouble in doing this: [How to boot the linux of riscv-poky on ZedBoard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737946/how-to-boot-the-linux-of-riscv-poky-on-zedboard)

Answer (score 3):

As of writing this answer the 1.9 ISA is still in development and you have the option of either sticking with the older and stable 1.7 ISA or switching to the new and unstable 1.9 ISA:

**Use the 1.7 ISA**

Stick with the 1.7 ISA and use the *master* branch of the riscv-tools and riscv-linux to build the gnu toolchain, spike, fesvr, bbl, pk and the Linux kernel. In this case, the command to run RISC-V Linux is the well known:

`sudo ./fesvr-zedboard +disk=/path/to/root.bin bbl /path/to/vmlinux`

If using this older ISA make sure that you generate with `rocket-chip` a compatible RISC-V core. Commit `648437e7cb909098d7418ffc72717b497674f651` from 15th of March is the closest to the master version of `riscv-tools` and works fine for me.

**Use the 1.9 ISA**

If you want to use the new 1.9 ISA, you will have to use the *priv-1.9* branch of `riscv-tools` and `riscv-linux` repositories. You must also generate a compatible RISC-V core with the latest version of `rocket-chip`.

The 1.9 version of these repositories does not include HTIF support for bbl (`riscv-tools`) and vmlinux (`riscv-linux`). And as the message the bbl prints after the RISC-V logo, you have to configure it with the `--with-payload` option. This is very easy to do:

```
export RISCV=/path/to/your/already/built/toolchain
cd riscv-tools/riscv-pk
mkdir build.with.payload
cd build.with.payload
../configure --prefix=$RISCV/riscv64-unknown-elf \
--host=riscv64-unknown-elf \
--with-payload=/path/to/vmlinux
```

You don't have to write any payload code that wraps vmlinux yourself, it is already provided in the `riscv-pk` repo. You also don't have to provide vmlinux as an argument to bbl when running it since it will now include the kernel binary. This has the effect of raising the size of bbl from ~60 KB to 3+ MB depending on how you configured your kernel.

Also since the new 1.9 ISA riscv-linux has removed support of HTIF, it doesn't have block device support anymore and the `+disk` argument will not work to specify a root disk image. You must instead boot using an initramfs ramdisk.

Thus the final command to run RISC-V Linux with the 1.9 ISA is the following:

`sudo ./fesvr-zedboard bbl`

Note that I still haven't tested the 1.9 ISA procedure described above, since for now my project is fine with the 1.7 ISA and I will wait for things to mature a bit until I switch.

[Reference issue on Github with zhemao's answer](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk/issues/18)